# Populate a cell based on information from a table but skip hidden rows

Tags: excel, hidden

Looking to have cells pull information from a table in sequence but ignore hidden rows from the source table.

I am currently pulling information from one table to another using the below code.

```
=IF(Table1!C9<>"",Table1!C9,"")
```

However, in table 1 there are some rows that have been intentionally hidden and I do not want to pull that information into the second worksheet and still want the second table to pull information without blank rows.

***Ex:***

**Table 1**

C9 Has Info

C10 Blank

C11 Has Info

**I would like Table 2 to populate as:**

C36 Has information from C9

C37 Has information from C11

*C10 was skipped because it was blank

Comment: You can integrate a [formula to check if a cell is hidden](https://superuser.com/a/885180/925350)

Comment: What are you doing with the results? II you are aggregating the results mathematically, you can probably just use the `SUBTOTAL` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aggregating the table mathematically, you can just use the `SUBTOTAL` function.

If you actually need the contents of the table, if you have `MS 365`, you can use this formula to return only the unhidden rows:

```
=FILTER(Table2,BYROW(Table2,LAMBDA(arr,SUBTOTAL(103,arr)>0)))
```